# validation directive with a small red strip at right or left side inside textbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm making validation directive with/using ng-model.

Target : If model is null, empty or undefined, it will give a small red strip inside particular text box.

Here is what i've done so far,    http://jsfiddle.net/R7HEV/11/   ... In my example, it converts whole background into red color when I want to have a small red strip at left or right side inside textbox only...

Confusion: I don't know how to make css which will generate a small red strip inside TEXTBOX only.

.css

```
.require{
    background:red;

}
```

.html

.js

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive("nxRequired", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",

        scope:{ngModel:"="},

        link: function (scope, attr, elem) {

            scope.$watch("ngModel", function (newVal, oldVal) {
                debugger
                if (newVal != undefined && newVal!="") {
                    elem.$removeClass("require");
                }

                else {
                    elem.$addClass("require");
                }


            });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This is a css question more than angular.

Comment: Yes problem belongs to Css. I don't know why have I put it inside angular? It happens sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right...

Change:

```
.require{
    background:red;
}
```

To:

```
.require {
    border-style:solid;
    border-left:2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as per your requirement `I want to have a small red strip at left or right side inside textbox only..`

apply below css class

```
.require{
  border-left: 3px solid red;
  border-right: 3px solid red;
}
```